# How to display selected image in mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material2

My goal is to display [Harvey Balls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_Balls) in a mat-select.  Originally I used Unicode, but found out that only Windows seems to have uniform sizes across each of the balls after testing iPhone, Android, and Linux.  Any styling corrections I made to the ball inside the option worked fine in the dropdown but not the selection. I switched to SVG and decided to do it as a module to easily support multiple css themes.

The issue that I am having is that the SVG does not appear on the selected value.  They appear fine in the drop down.

How do I get the selected value to render the same in both the selection and the dropdown?

harvey-ball.html

```
<svg width="14" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
<circle class="harvey-svg" cx="7" cy="7" r="6.5"></circle>
<path *ngIf="status >= 1" d="M 7,0 A 7,7 0 0 1 14,7 L 7,7 z" class="harvey-fill-svg"></path>
<path *ngIf="status >= 2" d="M 14,7 A 7,7 0 0 1 7,14 L 7,7 z" class="harvey-fill-svg"></path>
<path *ngIf="status >= 3" d="M 7,14 A 7,7 0 0 1 0,7 L 7,7 z" class="harvey-fill-svg"></path>
<path *ngIf="status == 4" d="M 0,7 A 7,7 0 0 1 7,0 L 7,7 z" class="harvey-fill-svg"></path>
```

harvey-ball.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-harvey-ball',
    templateUrl: './harvey-ball.html',
  })
export class HarveyBallComponent {
    @Input() status: number;
}
```

app.component.html

```
Current Status:
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus">
        <mat-option [value]=0><app-harvey-ball [status]=0></app-harvey-ball> Not Started</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=1><app-harvey-ball [status]=1></app-harvey-ball> Started</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=2><app-harvey-ball [status]=2></app-harvey-ball> In Progress</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=3><app-harvey-ball [status]=3></app-harvey-ball> Near Completion</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=4><app-harvey-ball [status]=4></app-harvey-ball> Complete</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g4epvw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular-material `mat-select` doesn't support html in the output dropdown. You can test this by just wrapping a strong around `Not <strong>Started</strong>` and notice that it doesn't copy into the dom. You'll have to roll your own image if you want it:

Something like:

```
Current Status:
<mat-form-field>
  <app-harvey-ball [status]=selectedStatus></app-harvey-ball>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus">
        <mat-option [value]=0>Not <strong>Started</strong></mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=1><app-harvey-ball [status]=1></app-harvey-ball> Started</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=2><app-harvey-ball [status]=2></app-harvey-ball> In Progress</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=3><app-harvey-ball [status]=3></app-harvey-ball> Near Completion</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=4><app-harvey-ball [status]=4></app-harvey-ball> Complete</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

But you'll have to fiddle with the css.

Comment: This was my last resort solution.  I was hoping I was missing something obvious.